# how to set profiling level on mongo through Perl

Tags: mongodb, perl

I want to use a Perl script to enable the profiling level in mongo, is there a way to execute this through Perl, corresponding shell command by logging into mongodb is

```
:- db.setProfilingLevel(2)
```

tried doing that using `run_command` feature but did not seem to work.

Comment: There is no built-in way to do that. https://grep.metacpan.org/search?q=setProfilingLevel&qd=MongoDB&qft=

Comment: Did you tried the run_command function ? see here: http://search.cpan.org/dist/MongoDB/lib/MongoDB/Tutorial.pod

Comment: @simbabque Um. [Yes there is](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/profile/#profile). The whole driver in fact merely implements invocations of `run_command` as everything in the MongoDB wire protocol is in fact that invocation. But the question really could have shown more effort.

Comment: @simbabque You're picking nits. For the OP. `$database->run_command([ profile => 2 ])`